# How to use dynamic name vue component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

- I want to use the name of the component is dynamic, i have a component menu with navigation to another components, so i want to get name the same of the current route. I have this:

```
export default{
 // name:'app',
 name: 'Dynamic name follow router name',
 data(){
  return{}
 }
}
```

`Note:` name of component the same of current route. I have two router, but it link to the same page.

- I tried this code below:

```
export default{
 name: '',// How can i use dynamic this name
 data(){
  return{}
 },
 created(){
  this.$options.name = this.$route.name
  this.getData()
 },
 methods:{
  function getData(){
   // Statement
  }
 }
}
```

**My purpose**
I want to keep-alive data from router when i change page

Comment: Do you mean, you want to keep the component cache if url changes. If yes, The keep-alive component caches the whole component, and not the component rendered depending on its URL. you can read more about keep-alive [here](https://itnext.io/yes-this-is-how-to-cache-pages-by-url-with-vue-vue-router-and-keep-alive-component-697ed76896e8#a357)

Comment: I have two router, i use one page for two router. I want to use name of component dynamic the follow of router name.

`
export default{
name:'Dynamic name', //how can i use dynamic name of component
data(){
 return{}
}
}
`